# undefined method for BSON Object - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a problem using rails and mongoid, I have created a rake task that loop on all School class, and find the 3 nearest premium-school, insert them in an Array field. So, I want to be able to display them on the view, but I have this error message :

```
undefined method `title' for BSON::ObjectId('573f11e808207e00030000a1'):BSON::ObjectId
```

Here is the taks :

```
namespace :geocodeschool do

  desc "Show premium school near non-premium school and update them"

  task :schgc => :environment do

      @schools = School.all

      def premium_school_aside(school)
        radius = 50
        @schools_a = School.near(school.coordinates.reverse, radius, units: :km)
        @schools_premium = @schools_a.premium_school.limit(3)
      end

      @schools.each do |school|
        premium_school_aside(school)
        puts "// -------------- //"
        puts "AUTO-ÉCOLE : #{school.title}"
        puts "// -------------- //"
        puts "les auto-écoles premiums près de #{school.title} : #{@schools_premium.count}"
        puts "-------"

        school.update(school_premium_asides: @schools_premium.map(&:id))

        puts "-------"

    end

  end

end
```

Here is the View :

```
  <% unless @school.is_subscribed? %>
    <% @schools_premium_aside.each do |spa| %>
      <p> <%= spa.title %> </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Here is the controller :

```
@schools_premium_aside = @school.school_premium_asides
```

And here is the model :

```
  # field for premium schools
  field :school_premium_asides, type: Array
```

Does someone know how could I access to the data to display the 3 premium school on the view ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your school model, you have field

`field :school_premium_asides, type: Array`

and you are storing only premium schools id's into that array here

```
school.update(school_premium_asides: @schools_premium.map(&:id))
```

But on view page you are trying get premium school title from that array, which you doesn't stored.

```
  <% unless @school.is_subscribed? %>
    <% @schools_premium_aside.each do |spa| %>
      <p> <%= spa.title %> </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**Posible Solution**:

In your controller query for those schools like this

```
@schools_premium_aside = School.where(id: { '$in' => @school.school_premium_asides }).only(:id, :title)
```

Comment: So I can't access to school attributes only with the id ? how could I do to store the Class School on this array and not only the id ?

Comment: Still are you facing any issue?? @AntoninMrchd

Comment: with : `@schools_premium_aside = School.where(id: { '$in' => @school.school_premium_asides }).only(:id, :title)` it work ! thank you very much !